# reading in a file from fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am reading in code from a file that looks like this "01/06/2009,Tom Sanders„264,220,73,260" I want to skip to the first comma and then start with the name. However when I read it in I am only getting the dates. I have used a format(T9,'(A)'), but it comes out in columns and is not what I  want. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We invite you to take the [tour] and learn [ask]. For we to be able to help you, you'd need to be more clear about your problem: what are you trying to get, what have you tried and what are you getting wrong? Consider providing a [mcve].

Comment: Have you tried a format statement that begins with 11X? This skips the first 11 spaces in the line.

Comment: yes I tried 11X, but  it still doesnt work. I think it might be my DO loop